# Symfony doctrine many to many unique

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have to entity with manyToMany relation, that i have transform in two OneToMany. So I have create an other Entity called CollanaCollezionista into that i have some attribute. 
I want that the couple collana/collezionista is unique, how can i do this on doctrine and symfony?

```
/**
* Collana
*/
class Collana
{

private $id;

private $titolo;

/**
 * @MaxDepth(1)
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CollezionistaCollana", mappedBy="collana")
 */
private $collezionisti;
}

/**
* Collezionista
*/
class Collezionista
{

private $id;

private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CollezionistaCollana", mappedBy="collezionista")
 */
private $collane;
}
```

So I have an other entity, called CollezionistaCollana. How can i set that the couple collezionista-collana is unique?

Comment: See if [@UniqueEntity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) or  [@UniqueConstraint](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-uniqueconstraint) do the stuff

Comment: that work like this

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UniqueConstraint as UniqueConstraint;

/**
 * CollezionistaCollana
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="collezionista_collana",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="unique_hold", columns={"idCollezionista", "idCollana"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CollezionistaCollana
{

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

[@UniqueConstraint](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-uniqueconstraint) do the stuff.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UniqueConstraint as UniqueConstraint;

/**
 * CollezionistaCollana
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="collezionista_collana",uniqueConstraints={@‌UniqueConstraint(nam‌​e="unique_hold", columns={"idCollezionista", "idCollana"})}) 
 * @ORM\Entity
 */ 
class CollezionistaCollana
{
    // Class details
}
```